# How to upgrade openssh?

Tags: debian, openssh

i want upgrade openssh, as i have error:

```
error: Unsafe AuthorizedKeysCommand: bad ownership or modes for file /usr/bin/get_ldap_ssh_key.sh
```

In `sshd_config`:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/get_ldap_ssh_key.sh
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
```

Bureport say  `Set all RESOLVED bugs to CLOSED with release of OpenSSH 7.1`

I not found instructions how to upgrade openssh. How to do it?

Comment: Which Linux/Unix/*ix are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a bug that upgrading will fix, but an error in your setup. The [`sshd_config(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html) manpage says

> **AuthorizedKeysCommand**
>
> Specifies a program to be used to look up the user's public keys.  The program must be owned by root, not
>                writable by group or others and specified by an absolute path.

You simply need to ensure that `/usr/bin/get_ldap_ssh_key.sh` satisfies these requirements:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/get_ldap_ssh_key.sh
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/get_ldap_ssh_key.sh
```

Comment: yep, file satisfies these requirements, but i have error

Comment: i reboot host and it work o_O